# add attribute when bottom of div scrolls above bottom of browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to have an attribute added to a certain div (`id="text1"`) when an other div (`id="one"`) scrolls above the bottom of the browser window. When the bottom of "one" scrolls below the bottom edge of the browser window again the attribute should be removed again.

This is the attribute I would like added and removed:

```
data-scroll-speed="2"
```

[**See example here**](https://jsfiddle.net/471bnvy4/3/)

Comment: Check this post for the solution:
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256564/changing-color-of-text-when-div-is-scrolled-above-certain-point)

Answer (score 1):

**1st**: you need to include jquery

**2nd**: you need to use  window `scroll` event

**3rd**: you need to get the `#two` `.offset().top` and `outerHeight()`

see the demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll' , function(){
    var WindowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        Div_one_top = $('#one').offset().top,
        Div_one_height = $('#one').outerHeight(true),
        Window_height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    if(WindowScrollTop >= (Div_one_top +  Div_one_height) - WindowScrollTop){
       $('#one').css('background' , 'red');
       $('#text1').removeAttr('data-scroll-speed');
    }else{
       $('#one').css('background' , 'black');
       $('#text1').attr('data-scroll-speed', '2');
    }
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
#one {
    height: 120vw;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#text1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 9em;
    margin-top: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
   color:white;
}

#two {
    height: 50vw;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
    <div id="text1">
        this is my text
    </div>
</div>
<div id="two">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mohamed-Yousef, but "one" is always higher than the scroll window. I need the attribute to be added when the bottomline of "one" is above the bottom line of the scroll window. And the attribute removed again when the bottomline of "one" is below the bottom line of the scroll window.

Comment: @Eddy as I pointed *may be you'll need to reverse the add/remove attribute up to your need*  .. answer updated

Comment: The solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256564/changing-color-of-text-when-div-is-scrolled-above-certain-point