# changing color of text when div is scrolled above certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like that the text changes color when the pink colored div is scrolled FULLY above the bottom egde of the browser window. When the pink colored div is scrolled partially below the bottom edge of the browser window again the text should be white again.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll' , function(){
    var WindowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        Div_one_top = $('#one').offset().top,
        Div_one_height = $('#one').outerHeight(true),
        Window_height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    if(WindowScrollTop >= (Div_one_top +  Div_one_height) - WindowScrollTop){
       $('#text1').css('color' , 'black');
    }else{
       $('#text1').css('color' , 'white');
    }
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
#one {
    height: 120vw;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#text1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 9em;
    margin-top: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
   color:white;
}

#two {
    height: 50vw;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
    <div id="text1">
        this is my text
    </div>
</div>
<div id="two">

</div>
```

Comment: if you want to change color of the text why not just do `$('#text1').css('color' , 'thecoloryouwant');`

Comment: Tank you and sorry @Carsten, I had an code error in my question. This is fixed now. My question however remains. Ik seems that the text does not change color at the exact moment that the bottom of the pink div comes above the bottom edge of the browser window.

Comment: The function $(this).scrollTop() get the scroll from the top of the window you have to add the window height with $(window).height().

Comment: When the browser window is scaled, the moment the text color changes is different and not when the bottom of the pink div comes above the bottom edge of the browser window.

Comment: Thanks, @iuberna, where is this placed in the code? Can you please update the code for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to compare sum of Window_height and WindowScrollTop:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll' , function(){
    var WindowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        Div_one_top = $('#one').offset().top,
        Div_one_height = $('#one').outerHeight(true),
        Window_height = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    if(WindowScrollTop+Window_height >= (Div_one_top +  Div_one_height) ){
       $('#text1').css('color' , 'black');
    }else{
       $('#text1').css('color' , 'white');
    }
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
#one {
    height: 120vw;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: pink;
}

#text1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 9em;
    margin-top: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
   color:white;
}

#two {
    height: 50vw;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
    <div id="text1">
        this is my text
    </div>
</div>
<div id="two">

</div>
```